# animation infographic / code or script (js + css) to replicate a icon/sv file multiple x

Tags: css, animation, icons, population

i have an icon / image, and need to make a animation graphic with it. like 'growth population' using person silhouette. an e.g: 
see the 'people infographics' in this image:
[image reference - people infographics](https://www.freepik.com/premium-vector/world-map-infographics-business-visualization-vector-elements_1279090.htm)
or 'male'/female in this url:
[referecen](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/set-of-infographic-elements-in-flat-style_2077259.htm)
i need this like an animation to use inside a website... using a svg icon, or image... to replicate x times. 
my case: '86 people have dedicated time for help poor children'.
any reference, idea, code to share? 
thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, you want to display an image on a page [x] times next to text "[x] people have dedicated time for help poor children"?
You'll need to use JS for that, duplicate the image and write it to the Dom

Comment: hi, sorry for my explanation. my english is not so good. i want to have a icon multiplique x times in a div, like a gif. but with js and css. to customize more easily.